How to add a second y-axis to a bar chart?
I have been trying to add a second y-axis (showing percentages) to my highcharter plot, however I cannot get it right.
Using dummy data such as this one:
# Sample data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  Name = LETTERS[1:5],
  Type = paste0("Type ", c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)),
  Value = rnorm(5, 150, 10)
)
df$Percentage = df$Value / sum(df$Value)

I can achieve what I'm trying to do using ggplot like this:
# ggplot with 2 axis
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Type, y=Value, fill=Name)) + 
  geom_col(position="stack") + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / sum(df$Value), labels = scales::label_percent())) + 
  theme_light()

But in highcharter, the second y-axis is only visible if I add another series to my plot, such as shown here:
library(highcharter)
highchart2() |> 
  hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(
      borderWidth = 0, 
      stacking = "normal",
      tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2)
    )
  ) |> 
  hc_add_series(data = df, hcaes(x = Type, y = Value, group = Name), type = "column") |>
  hc_add_series(data = df, hcaes(x = Type, y = Percentage, group = Name), type = "column", yAxis = 1) |>
  hc_xAxis(type="category") |> 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 0, title = list(text="Amount")),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text="Percentage"))
  )

However, when turning the second series invisible, using the visible=F argument, the tick values of my second y-axis disappear and all I have left is its title.
Is it possible to do what I am trying to do using highcharter?

Please try title = list(text=""). Is this what you intended? Keep title "Percentage" invisible?

@NearLin
No, the title is fine. The second y-axis itself does not show any values if I hide the percentage series. I.e. I just want to display the value series while having both the value and percentage y-axes without displaying the percentage series itself.

Instead of setting the visible option to false I suggest changing color to transparent, disabling tooltip and removing the series from the legend. Then the axis is displayed correctly even though there are no actual points on the chart. Here's how it looks like in js: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/70qa9snz/

@DominikChudy This works. Thank you so much!
